# How to transform this side-effect into an elegant chaining of Vapor operations?

Tags: swift, vapor

I am starting using Vapor to run an API, and I couldn't figure out an *elegant* way of doing the following: (1) load a Fluent relation and (2) wait for the response of an HTTP callback before (3) responding to the original request.

Here is what I ended up coding, after I transformed my real-life entities into planets and stars to maintain the examples from Vapor's documentation. It works™️, but I couldn't achieve a nice chaining of operations ☹️.

```swift
    func flagPlanetAsHumanFriendly(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Planet> {
        Planet(req.parameters.get("planetID"), on: req.db)
            .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
            .flatMap { planet in
                // I load the star because I need its ID for the HTTP callback
                _ = planet.$star.load(on: req.db).map {
                    let uri = URI(scheme: "http", host: "localhost", port: 4200, path: "/webhooks/star")
                    // HTTP Callback
                    req.client.post(uri) { req in
                        try req.content.encode(
                            WebhookDTO(
                                starId: planet.star.id!,
                                status: .humanFriendly,
                                planetId: planet.id!
                            ),
                            using: JSONEncoder()
                        )
                    }
                    .map { res in
                        debugPrint("\(res)")
                        return
                    }
                }

                // Couldn't find a way to wait for the response, so the HTTP callback is a side-effect
                // and its response is not used in the original HTTP response...
                // If the callback fails, my API can't report it. 
                planet.state = .humanFriendly
                return planet.save(on: req.db).map { planet }
            }
    }
```

### Issue #1. Combining 2 `EventLoopFuture`

My first issue was that I couldn't find a way to load a parent relationship while keeping the entity in the scope.

```swift
Planet(req.parameters.get("planetID"), on: req.db)
    .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
    .flatMap { planet in // planet is in the scope 
        return planet.$star.load(on: req.db) // returns a EventLoopFuture<Void>
    }
    .map {
      // I know that star has been loaded but I lost my `planet` reference ☹️
      ???
    }
```

I assume there is an operator that should be able to return a mix of the 2 `EventLoopFuture` instances but I couldn't figure it out.

### Issue #2. Chaining `EventLoopFuture` with an auxiliary HTTP request's response

Here as well, I assume I miss an operator that allows me to wait for the request's response, while keeping a reference to the planet, before I respond to the original request.

---

Help would be welcome on how to achieve this in a nice chaining of operations — if it is possible, of course — and I will more than happy to update Vapor's documentation accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, if you need the result of one future inside the result of another future then you have to nest the callbacks - you can't use chaining. So for instance:

```swift
Planet(req.parameters.get("planetID"), on: req.db)
    .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
    .flatMap { planet in // planet is in the scope 
        return planet.$star.load(on: req.db).map {
            // Star is now eager loaded and you have access to planet
        }
    }
```

If you have multiple futures that aren't reliant on each other but you need the results of both you can use `and` to chain the two together and wait for them. E.g.:

```swift
func flagPlanetAsHumanFriendly(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Planet> {
    Planet(req.parameters.get("planetID"), on: req.db)
        .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
        .flatMap { planet in
            // I load the star because I need its ID for the HTTP callback
            planet.$star.load(on: req.db).map {
                let uri = URI(scheme: "http", host: "localhost", port: 4200, path: "/webhooks/star")
                // HTTP Callback
                let postFuture = req.client.post(uri) { req in
                    try req.content.encode(
                        WebhookDTO(
                            starId: planet.star.id!,
                            status: .humanFriendly,
                            planetId: planet.id!
                        ),
                        using: JSONEncoder()
                    )
                }.map { res in
                    debugPrint("\(res)")
                    return
                }

                planet.state = .humanFriendly
                let planetUpdateFuture = planet.save(on: req.db)

                return postFuture.and(planetUpdateFuture).flatMap { _, _ in
                    return planet
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer @0xTim. Back from holidays, and ready to rock this solution. 